# Implementation of Speck cipher

Tags: encryption, implementation

I am trying to implement the speck cipher as specified here: [Speck Cipher](https://eprint.iacr.org/2013/404.pdf). On page 18 of the document you can find some speck pseudo-code I want to implement.

It seems that I got a problem on understanding the pseudo-code. As you can find there, `x` and `y` are plaintext words with length `n`. `l[m-2],...l[0]`, `k[0]` are key words (as for words, they have length `n` right?). When you do the key expansion, we iterate for `i` from `0` to `T-2`, where `T` are the round numbers (for example 34). However I get an `IndexOutofBoundsException`, because the array with the `l`'s has only `m-2` positions and not `T-2`.

Can someone clarify what the key expansions does and how?

Comment: did you create 'k' with enough size? You should at least post a minimal code to get a proper answer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Ah, I get where the confusion lies:

```
l[m-2],...l[0], k[0]
```

these are the *input* key words, in other words, they represent *the key*. These are **not** declarations of the size of the arrays, as you might expect if you're a developer.

*Then* the subkey's in array `k` should be derived, using array `l` for intermediate values.

According to the formulas, taking the largest `i`, i.e. `i_max = T - 2` you get a highest index for array `l` of `i_max + m - 1 = T - 2 + m - 1 = T + m - 3` and therefore a size of the array of one more: `T + m - 2`. The size of a zero-based array is always the index of the last element - plus one, after all.

Similarly, for subkey array `k` you get a highest index of `i_max + 1`, which is `T - 2 + 1` or `T - 1`. Again, the size of the array is one more, so there are `T` elements in `k`. This makes a lot of sense if you require `T` round keys :)

Note that it seems possible to simply redo the subkey derivation for each round if you require a minimum of RAM. The entire `l` array doesn't seem necessary either. For software implementations that doesn't matter a single iota of course.

Comment: Thank you very much, that helps me a lot! :)